# Deploy working polymer app to android using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, polymer

Yes,We have resources for this on net and I searched for that ,But it didn't solve my problem so asking this question here.
I have a working polymer web app and I am able to access this using http://localhost:8080//index.html,My app looks like this

[image]
I want to deploy this app in android phone,So I used [apache cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)
Below are the steps I followed

1. Installed cordova using

> npm install -g cordova.

2. create cordova project

   > cordova create alertsDir com.alerts.net "Alerts" --template=C:/Users/212606402/Learning/Alert client/alert-push-notification-client
3. cd to alertsDir and add platform

> cordova platform add android

4. build platform

> cordova build android

5. run project

> cordova run android

I am not getting any error in above steps

I run this in both android emulator and nexus 5 devise but it showing the same default cordova screen,My app is not shown there,Below is the emulator screen I am seeing

[image]
I followed some tutorials and just wondering how it works for them.

[tuetorial 1](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-to-do-list-app-with-polymer-and-cordova--cms-25434)
Can anyone please explain me what I am missing or doing wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're building the cordova sample app and now you are wondering that shows the cordova sample app?

Comment: @Phonolog, Hi thanks for your reply, I am not deploying the cordova sample app, I am trying to deploy my polymer app,But in output I am getting cordova sample app. I don't know what I need to change

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, Cordova only deploy 2 folder platforms folder and www folder but not all in platforms folder will get deployed to your device, usually the cli will merge platform_www and www folder.
so if you want to make a cordova app you need to put all your sourcecode or sourcecode that already bundeled using either polymer-build with gulp or polymer-cli inside www directory.

Comment: After doing that it shows an empty screen, but still no luck

Comment: did you use iron-route ? if so then you need to add hash-as-path attribute to iron-route

Comment: No. Is iron-route still available in Polymer 2? I see in the documentation it's app-route: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/routing It's not important but here's my code: https://github.com/cvielma/ethicality/blob/polymer/src/my-app.html